# Disable windows button, alt e uppercase with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create application web "QUIZ ", In the application use the mouse only, I have disabled all keys except keys `windows`, `alt`,'num lock' and `caps` button. I want Into application to disable the `windows`, `alt` and `caps` button with the following code but it doesn't work:

```js
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
        return false;
}

    $(document).keydown(function (event) {
        // Prevent ALT -  Prevent  left window key  -  Prevent caps lock
        if (event.keyCode == 18 || event.keyCode == 91 || event.keyCode == 20) {
            console.log("clicked", event.keyCode);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear with what you're asking, and/or elaborate on your use case? Are you suggesting you want to use code in a browser to disable modifier keys in the underlying OS? If this was possible, wouldn't this be an incredibly dangerous security risk for end users?

Comment: Why on Earth would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If it were, it would be a security concern. Websites can never modify standard browser or operating system behavior and it is a waste of time to try to do so, as bugs that allow it to be done will be fixed very quickly.